# TexStudio "Go to source" and \import

Tags: texstudio

When using `\import` to store chapters in separate files, I am losing the ability to go from PDF to source and vice versa (except that compiling does take me to the right spot in the PDF). I am on 2.12.4 due to the reasons out of scope of this question. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: There is a popup menu on the PDF viewer, which has a menu option "Go to source", and vice versa, on the source editor there is a popup menu, which has "Go to PDF". Both do not work when using `import` package. I thought it was obvious.

Comment: OK have used \import package and am using default settings in 2.12.14 & All works as expected Go to pdf from the import file jumps to main PDF and highlight a line in PDF go to source  opens and highlights that import file line in the editor. Similar with main file, you will need to provide an mwe to show how it does not work for you

Comment: When I create very simple one-liner MWE, it works. But it does not work in the 600+ page book which I am typesetting. This either hits some limitation of TexStudio, or it is simply a bug, but 9 chapters for about 1.1 MB of LaTex source does not move me in either direction: from source to PDF or from PDF to source. I do not know what else you are looking for.

Comment: I tried answer showing the way synctex works odd with TXS, but got bogged down trying to show number of locations it does not jump as expected. Your experience seems different based on sheer volume of cross indexing. A possible workaround is to compile outside TXS (either at command line (or in windows the default copy of TeXworks) the system built synctex file should be respected by TXS. Worth a try to see if its different to the one built via TXS (If behaviour is same then its a synctex issue with \input methodology, if not its TeXstudio builds using multiphases compiles in the background)